# Как правильно использовать enable_shared_from_this?

Tags: c++

Я пытаюсь понять, зачем вообще нужно использовать `enable_shared_from_this`?

Я нашел, вот такое обьяснение

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5548314/5709159

где вкратце говориться о том, что вот так плохо

```
    struct S
    {
        shared_ptr<S> dangerous()
        {
            return shared_ptr<S>(this);   // don't do this!
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        shared_ptr<S> sp1(new S);
        shared_ptr<S> sp2 = sp1->dangerous();
        return 0;
    }
```

а вот так хорошо

```
    struct S : enable_shared_from_this<S>
    {
        shared_ptr<S> not_dangerous()
        {
            return shared_from_this();
        }
    };

    int main()
    {
        shared_ptr<S> sp1(new S);
        shared_ptr<S> sp2 = sp1->not_dangerous();
        return 0;
    }
```

Тут вопросов нет и действительно при данном сравнении понятно, что правильно, а что нет.

Но в чем проблема сделать просто вот так

```
int main()
{
    shared_ptr<S> sp1(new S);
    shared_ptr<S> sp2 = sp1;
    return 0;
}
```

И не нужно ничего придумывать, ни от чего наследовать и переопределять.

В чем хитрость?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Хитрость в том, что предложенный вами способ работает только за пределами членов класса. Но что если нужно создать `shared_ptr` на объект класса из метода этого класса? В качестве [примера](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_69_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp11/echo/async_tcp_echo_server.cpp) где это может понадобится (хотя в таком случае я предпочитаю использовать `coroutines`

Comment: за что минус то?